Download link for Anzo SDK zip file is not available
In Anzo graph documentation, Anzo SDK zip file is mentioned.
Please provide link for the download. In the doc only steps are mentioned to deploy the SDK, but download link is not provided.
Ref link -https://docs.cambridgesemantics.com/anzo/v5.4/userdoc/sdk-deploy.htm
The Anzo SDK contains three projects, which I want to access:

com.cambridgesemantics.anzo.sdk

com.cambridgesemantics.anzo.sdk.server

com.cambridgesemantics.anzo.sdk.api


